# Is it legal to reference an enum instance as a field of another instance of that type?

Tags: java, enums, static-members

```
enum Day{SAT,SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THURS,FRI}

class Plan{
    Day d;

    public plan(Day d)
    {
        this.d=d;
    }

    Day getDay()
    {
        return d;
    }
}

class tester{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Plan p=new Plan(Day.SAT);

        Day e=p.getDay();

        System.out.println(e.MON);
    }
}
```

In the main function `e` is intialized with `Day.SAT`, but why  is `e.MON` not an error? Does it make sense initializing it?

Comment: Why would it throw an error? It's doing exactly as you're telling it to do.

If you want to output the day you initialized you should just `System.out.println(e);`

Your current code wont throw an error but it will throw a warning about static access. (e.MON isn't static access, you would use Day.MON)

Also, just as a quick FYI, you should label your classes in camel case: http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: I took the liberty to remove some code that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: please read
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html I know it is off topic, but I do this for all people who will have the bad luck to read your code, because to me, it is a pain.

Comment: Try replacing `e` with `Day e = null;` and see what happens ;)

Comment: @SHTester Please don't use 'throw' in connection with compiler errors. Exceptions are thrown, at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Enum values are pretty much "only" `static final` fields. In Java you can access static fields via a reference. You *should not* do that, however because it's confusing.

In essence these two lines do the same thing (assuming there's a `Day e` define somewhere above them):

```
System.out.println(Day.MON); // sane, normal way
System.out.println(e.MON); // supported, but discouraged way.
```

Answer (score 0):

e.MON is "like" accessing static member of a class through an instance variable of that class, and so no error will be shown.